# I got this error when I tried to "Insert guest additions CD image..."how to solve this error which is mentation below and my host OS is windows

Tags: virtualbox, disk, optical

Unable to insert the virtual optical disk C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the machine ubuntu 20.04.

Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
Callee: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}

Comment: How does this relate to Ubuntu ?

Comment: You may be getting that error simply because the disk is already mounted - check with `ls /media/$USER`

Answer (score 0):

One has to use the other start methods from the falling menu next to the green :arrow: . These are the "Headless Start" and "Detachable Start", which appear on the falling menu and not to use "Normal Start".